# Netlify deploy fails on Gatsby build

Tags: dns, command, gatsby, continuous-deployment, netlify

```html
4:51:19 PM: Build ready to start
4:51:21 PM: build-image version: 9cade8af58c2cf3a17a1e9433d2e979149488837
4:51:21 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.5
4:51:21 PM: buildbot version: 036f37945d6de439a17a554b3ae02e2f8f0f1fb0
4:51:21 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
4:51:21 PM: Starting to download cache of 254.9KB
4:51:21 PM: Finished downloading cache in 87.118057ms
4:51:21 PM: Starting to extract cache
4:51:21 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
4:51:21 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
4:51:21 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
4:51:21 PM: git clone https://github.com/AlexanderArchambeault/paintingslive2
4:51:22 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
4:51:23 PM: Starting build script
4:51:23 PM: Installing dependencies
4:51:24 PM: Downloading and installing node v10.18.1...
4:51:24 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.18.1/node-v10.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
4:51:25 PM: 
####################################################
4:51:25 PM:                   72.5%
4:51:25 PM: 
###############################################
4:51:25 PM: ######################### 100.0%
4:51:25 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
4:51:25 PM: Checksums matched!
4:51:27 PM: Now using node v10.18.1 (npm v6.13.4)
4:51:27 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
4:51:29 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
4:51:29 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
4:51:29 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
4:51:29 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
4:51:29 PM: unset GOOS;
4:51:29 PM: unset GOARCH;
4:51:29 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
4:51:29 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
4:51:29 PM: go version >&2;
4:51:29 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
4:51:29 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
4:51:29 PM: Installing missing commands
4:51:29 PM: Verify run directory
4:51:29 PM: Executing user command: gatsby build
4:51:29 PM: /usr/local/bin/build: line 64: gatsby: command not found
4:51:29 PM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
4:51:29 PM: Caching artifacts
4:51:29 PM: Started saving pip cache
4:51:29 PM: Finished saving pip cache
4:51:29 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Started saving go dependencies
4:51:29 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
4:51:32 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
4:51:32 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
4:51:32 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
4:51:32 PM: Finished processing build request in 11.100770754s
```

So this error wont go away, and it must be a problem with "/usr/local/bin/build: line 64: gatsby: command not found" and some incompatibillity with linux. but ive been slaving away at this website to only get errors in deployment! Any help in solving this with me would be very apreciated.

Comment: What other things have you tried? Does it work with other Linux versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. It's probably not an incompatibility. The error tells you that at the specified repository directory, the build command cannot find the files to kick off the gatsby build process because they are not there.

Netlify by default [(see docs)](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#gatsby) assumes your gatsby project is at the root of your linked repository. If it is in a folder like `/projectFolder/` you need to tell netlify:

- go to `https://app.netlify.com/sites/yourSite/settings/deploys`
- edit settings >

`Base directory: projectFolder`

`Publish directory: projectFolder/public`